# How to add 3rd party Library files&folder(CSVreader or OpenCsv) in my java class file?

Tags: java

I am facing an issue with adding 3rd party library files - csvreader or Opencsv folder.  Here, I added the com-folder(CSVReader)-https://sourceforge.net/projects/java-csvreader-and-csvwriter/ in the lib folder.  But in my IDE it is showing an error suggesting that it's not there. I'm not clear where or in which folder to add those library files; could someone guide me on this?

[image]

Comment: This becomes easier if you're using Maven or Gradle.  Either of those tools ring a bell for you?

Comment: It could also help if you mentioned what IDE you're using.  Eclipse, by the look of it.

Comment: For Eclipse: [How do I add an extra library to my project's classpath](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F).  But yeah, as mentioned - look into Maven or Gradle for solutions that don't depend on a specific IDE.  I prefer Gradle.  I use the IntelliJ IDE, which seems to have nice Gradle support.  If you want to edit your classpath by hand in Eclipse - check for a `.classpath` file in your project's root folder.